# If an overflow gasket does not fit, can it be rotated?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

Our new tub is very vertical at the supply/drain side at the overflow hole. The drain fitting we have slopes backwards very slightly where it connects. The rubber gasket for the overflow is very steeply beveled (~1/8" to 3/8" thickness). It appears to fit *better* if the thick part is at the top and I've seen comments online that both say [thick to top](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&id=547DFB013DB280BC33B654E6F7358020896F18A5&thid=OIP.l7N-M1jIDk8KsDMEPmx0kAHaHa&exph=550&expw=550&q=bathtub%20overflow%20gasket&selectedindex=95&vt=0&eim=1,2,6) and [thick to bottom](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&id=4BC958A5B268770E7CD1F58F5BE2CB3822DAED8F&thid=OIP.YtzE-WmBpDJOTx203QmdIQHaGv&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi2.wp.com%2Fedmondbathtubrefinishing.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F04%2FBathtub-Drain-and-Plumbing-Diagram-5.jpeg&exph=670&expw=736&q=Bathtub%20Overflow%20Diagram&selectedindex=1&ajaxhist=0&vt=0&eim=1,2,6).

When fitting thick to top, it fits closer, but not enough to seal the bottom. When fitting thick to bottom, it has a snug bottom, but a large gap after halfway.

I saw some posts saying you can rotate the gasket and get a good fit in cases where neither work and it *seems* to work that way. Everything at least fits, but is this a poor solution? I can't seem to get anything not quite as sloped. Would silicone caulk fix a thick top/bottom situation?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the rubber gasket you have with a more pliable foam-rubber replacement (commonly available at plumbing shops). This should allow you to place the gasket in the normal position (thick at bottom) but to give it a squeeze to effect a seal all the way around.

In the end, it is the seal at the bottom that is most important. Why? Because any water that gets to the overflow *under normal circumstances* is just incidental splashing and not likely to cause a huge problem. In the worst case (actual high water level, the reason for the overflow port), large amounts of water will be flowing through the *bottom* part of the hole. Any gap there will result in floor/wall/home flooding and damage.

Comment: I agree with Jimmy. Get another gasket and skip the caulk.